# Random Iteration Loop in R

Tags: r, loops, random

I would like to make a for loop that loops through the numbers `1-length(Matrix$Index)` in a random order. Note that every number can only be visited once.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look for `?sample`

Comment: `sample(1:(1-length(Matrix$index)), size=1, replace=FALSE)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for (i in sample(c(1:length(Matrix$Index))))` will achieve this.

You can achieve different samples by changing the seed with `set.seed()`. Setting a specific seed per sample will allow for reproducability.

Comment: When I try it, it produces repeats.

Comment: Works! Thanks, Friend.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question perfectly, but I guess you try to perform I kind of re-sampling without replacement on your vector, if you want to use R built-in function `sample()`, then:

```
n<-10
x<-rnorm(n)
resampled<-sample(x,length(x),replace=F)
```

Note that I'm using a simulated data (x) from a N(0,1) distribution. If you for any reason want to apply a loop, just try something like:

```
resampled<-numeric(n)

for(i in 1:n){
              a<-sample(1:n,1)
              resampled[i]<-x[a]
              x<-x[-a]
              n<-n-1
              }
```